# Self-consistent non-linear eigenproblem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-optimization, generalized-eigenvector

Given two Hermitian matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ of dimension $M \times M$, search for a set of $N \leq M$ orthonormal vectors $\mathbf{v}_n$ for which

$$\left( a_n \mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B} \right) \mathbf{v}_n=\lambda_n \mathbf{v}_n\;$$

where $\;a_n=\mathbf{v}_n^\dagger \mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}_n$, holds such that $\sum_n \lambda_n \rightarrow \max$.

Here, $\dagger$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose of a matrix/vector.

Is this problem solvable and if, how to solve it?

*My thoughts so far:*

First, the problem makes sense. Since $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are hermitian both the $a_n$ and $\lambda_n$ are real and it makes sense to ask for the maximum of the sum.

My first idea was to solve the problem iteratively:
For each $n=1,\dots,N$ guess an initial $a_n$ (e.g. $a_n=1$), solve the eigenvalue problem and choose as $\mathbf{v}_n$ the eigenvector corresponding to the $n$-th largest eigenvalue $\lambda_n$, with this update $a_n$ and reiterate until self-consistency is reached. The problem with this method (besides possible convergence issues) is that each $\mathbf{v}_n$ comes from an individual diagonalization and thus the resulting $\mathbf{v}_n$ are not necessarily orthogonal.

The second idea/question that came to my mind was if the problem can be cast into a non-linear (quadratic?) eigenproblem that then can be solved with standard techniques?

Thank you very much for your suggestions, comments and advice!

> P.S. (go on reading if you are interested in the origin of the problem)
>   This problem comes from an optimization problem in quantum physics. In the following, I will use the Bra-Ket notation commonly used in physics ($\langle f|g \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\; f^\ast(\mathbf{r}) g(\mathbf{r})$ with $\ast$ denoting the complex conjugate). The goal is to minimize the functional
>   $$\Omega[\lbrace w_n\rbrace ] = \sum_n [\langle w_n|\hat{\mathbf{R}}^2|w_n \rangle - \langle w_n|\hat{\mathbf{R}}|w_n \rangle^2]\rightarrow \mathrm{min}\;,$$
>   where $\hat{\mathbf{R}}$ is an operator and $\lbrace|w_n\rangle \rbrace$ a set of $N$ orthonormal states/functions ($\langle w_m|w_n \rangle = \delta_{mn}$). Taking the derivative
>   $$\frac{\delta \Omega}{\delta w_n^\ast} = \hat{\mathbf{R}}^2 |w_n\rangle - 2\langle w_n|\hat{\mathbf{R}}|w_n \rangle \hat{\mathbf{R}} |w_n\rangle$$
>   and adding orthonormality as a constraint with Lagrangian multipliers $\Lambda_{mn}$, we need to solve
>   $$\frac{\delta \Omega}{\delta w_n^\ast} + \sum_m \Lambda_{mn}\frac{\delta}{\delta w_n^\ast}[\langle w_n|w_m\rangle - \delta_{mn}] = 0\;.$$
>   Using a unitary transformation that diagonalizes $\Lambda$, this can be written as
>   $$\frac{\delta \Omega}{\delta w_n^\ast} + \lambda_n |w_n\rangle = 0\;.$$
>   Now, expressing the states in an orthonormal basis $\lbrace|g_i\rangle\rbrace$ ($|w_n\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^M v_{in}|g_i\rangle$), this leads me to the above stated problem with the matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ being the follwing matrix elements of the operators $A_{ij} = \sqrt{2}\langle g_i|\hat{\mathbf{R}}|g_j\rangle$ and $B_{ij} = -\langle g_i|\hat{\mathbf{R}}^2|g_j\rangle$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have adopted your changes and added information about the origin of the problem.

Comment: Don't $A$ and $B$ commute in your motivating problem? It seems to me that we should have $B=-A^2/2$.

Comment: @Rahul I think, you are right under the following assumptions: first, with $A^2$ you mean $\mathbf{A}^2=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}$ (and not the squares of the elements) and second, $\hat{\mathbf{R}} |g_i \rangle \in \mathrm{span}\lbrace |g_i \rangle \rbrace$. Let's assume that these assumptions are fulfilled. What does this additional piece of information mean for the solution?

Comment: Ah, I guess you're right about the second assumption. Anyway, then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, and their unit eigenvectors form a set of orthonormal $v_n$'s satisfying your condition. I'm not sure how to prove whether there are other feasible vectors.